# Redis doesn't delete records from the database

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

First of all, I'm using this wrapper: https://github.com/garywoodfine/redis-mvc-core/blob/master/RedisConfiguration/RedisVoteService.cs and `Delete(...)` doesn't seem to work. I think I tried `IDistributedCache` and it used to not delete the object as well but it at least null'd all properties.

You can see in the comments that I tried `FlushDatabase()` but it didn't seem to work too. I want Delete method to delete the objects. Not only null them (this doesn't work as well).

Any ideas? I would honestly like to get a better wrapper that supports `List<T>`.

[image]

```cs
var redis = new RedisAlgorithmService<BotSession>(_connectionFactory);
var test = redis.Get("Test");
if (test == null)
    redis.Save("Test", new BotSession(TrendType.Uptrend, bot.Id));
test.NTimes = 123;
redis.Delete("Test");
```

```cs
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System;

namespace Binance.Redis
{
    public class RedisAlgorithmService<T> : BaseService<T>, IRedisService<T>
    {
        internal readonly IRedisConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
        protected readonly IDatabase _database;

        public RedisAlgorithmService(IRedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
        {
            _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
            _database = _connectionFactory.Connection().GetDatabase();
        }

        public void Delete(string key)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) || key.Contains(":")) 
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid key!");

            key = GenerateKey(key);
            _database.KeyDelete(key);

            // _database.HashDelete(key, );

            // var endpoints = _connectionFactory.Connection().GetEndPoints();
            // _connectionFactory.Connection().GetServer(endpoints[0]).FlushDatabase();
        }

        public T Get(string key)
        {
            key = GenerateKey(key);
            var hash = _database.HashGetAll(key);
            return MapFromHash(hash);
        }

        public void Save(string key, T obj)
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                var hash = GenerateHash(obj);
                key = GenerateKey(key);

                if (_database.HashLength(key) == 0)
                {
                    _database.HashSet(key, hash);
                }
                else
                {
                    var props = Properties;
                    foreach (var item in props)
                    {
                        if (_database.HashExists(key, item.Name))
                        {
                            _database.HashIncrement(key, item.Name, Convert.ToInt32(item.GetValue(obj)));
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if `FlushDatabase()` or `FlushAllDatabase()` is exactly what you want:

- FLUSHDB – Deletes all keys from the connection's current database.
- FLUSHALL – Deletes all keys from all databases.

There is another workaround using extension methods and `Newtonsoft.Json` as a serializer/deserializer. I understand that `IDistributedCache` supports only string/byte array as input and you can't pass class objects to it and this workaround will help you do that.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = "localhost";
    options.InstanceName = "name";
});
```

CacheExtensions.cs

```
namespace TestProject.Extensions
{
    public static class CacheExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<T> SetAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, T item)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

            await cache.SetStringAsync(key, json);

            return await cache.GetAsync<T>(key);
        }

        public static async Task<T> SetAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, T item, int expirationInHours)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

            await cache.SetStringAsync(key, json, new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
            {
                AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(expirationInHours)
            });

            return await cache.GetAsync<T>(key);
        }

        public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
        {
            var json = await cache.GetStringAsync(key);

            if (json == null)
                return default;

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

DI `IDistributedCache`:

```
private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;

public TestService(IDistributedCache cache)
{
    _cache = cache;
}
```

and use it like that:

```
List<Test> testList = new List<Test>
{
    new Test(...),
    new Test(...)
};

var test = await _cache.GetAsync<List<Test>>("ListKey");
await _cache.SetAsync("ListKey", testList);
await _cache.RemoveAsync("ListKey");

var test2 = await _cache.GetAsync<Test>("key");
await _cache.SetAsync("key", new Test(...));
await _cache.RemoveAsync("key");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps you. I could see this method you tried but seems incomplete.

Try removing the Hash as well.

```
DeleteHash(string key, string cacheSubKey)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Some problem here !");

            _database.HashDelete(key, cacheSubKey);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it is incomplete because I don't know how to use it. @smilyface

Comment: I don't have `cacheSubKey`.